# MongoDB on Azure Web APP

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure

I'm running nodejs application via Azure Web App. How do I set up MongoDB on Web App service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provision MongoDB yourself and have your Web App work against it.
Azure doesn't have a native MongoDB service but you can:

- Use Azure's DocumentDB with the [Mongo driver compatibility](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-protocol-mongodb/)
- Use the [MongoDB VM image](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/partners/bitnami/mongodb/) from the marketplace (this is IaaS).
- Use mLab which is a 3rd party hosted solution but can be bought from Azure

Comment: Thanks, now I see how to deal with my problem!

Comment: Please keep in mind, that mLab is now part of MongoDB atlas. Clients are advised to migrate, why I would not suggest using mLab any more. Check https://docs.mlab.com/mlab-to-atlas/ for more details.